# How can i set a git repository to ignore all previous commits and start from a new initial commit?

Tags: git, github

I am new to version control software so in an attempt to get familiar with git I decided to use it in my unreal project. I'm using LFS but my file size became too large for a free package and so I initially made another commit after reducing the file size (I've become aware that this is a common rookie error). Bottom line is I want to just start from scratch where I'm currently at so I don't lose any of the work I've done since this issue. How should I go about doing this? I've tried rebasing my commits and it didn't really work, I'm unsure as to why.

Do I just need to start from scratch with a new repository or are there other alternatives?

I feel there should be an inbuilt option on git to ignore all previous changes and just start tracking changes from the current state as surely issues like this must need overcoming regularly?

Comment: Do you plan to push it into github or any other repo hosting services that restrict blob size? If that's not the case, there's no need to use LFS.

Comment: @eftshift0 Yeah, me and another developer are working on this project together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to set yourself so that you start on a completely new branch with no history is:

```
git checkout --orphan new-branch
# this new branch has _no_ history
git commit -m "First revision"
# then you can move main to this new revision
git branch -f main
git checkout main
```

Then you can force-push this new branch into a repository of your preference. I have no experience with LSF so I don't know how that part plays out.

Comment: Note one difference between `git checkout --orphan` and `git switch --orphan`: the latter has the side effect of *emptying out the index* (reading the empty tree into the index), which removes the current commit from the index/staging-area and from your working tree. Using `git checkout --orphan` leaves these in place. So you should pick whichever of these more suits what you want to happen next. If you pick the wrong one by mistake, it's easy to recover, just remove all files (`git rm -rf .` for instance) or repopulate (`git restore`), but it's worth knowing.